Sympy solve solutions missing
Sympy's solve method doesn't return all solutions on this relatively simple problem:
import sympy as sp
y1, y2, x = sp.symbols('y1 y2 x')

y1 = x**2
y2 = x

sp.solve(y1, y2, dict = True)

This returns [{x: 0}] but there should be an x=1 solution as well.
Am I using this correctly?

The output is correct given the input shown. You are asking to solve the equation x^2=0 for x and the result says that x=0 is the only solution. Your symbols y1 and y2 don't do anything because you assign over them but presumably you intended this to mean something different from what it does mean.

You are trying to find the intersection between a parabola and a straight line. If you were to do it by hand, you would write:
step 1: x**2 = x
step 2: x**2 - x = 0
step 3: x * (x - 1) = 0
step 4: x = 0, x = 1

So, you have to inform sympy that the equation you are trying to solve is x**2 - x:
import sympy as sp
x = sp.symbols('x')

y1 = x**2
y2 = x
eq = y1 - y2

sp.solve(eq, x, dict = True)
# [{x: 0}, {x: 1}]


There is a mistake in your code, sp.solve(y1, y2, dict=True) is incorrect because "solve" search equations and variables to solve. Thus you should pass equation to solve and not just expression.
Have a look at the below given code snippet:
Method:-01

    import sympy as sp
    
    x = sp.symbols('x')
    y1 = x**2
    y2 = x
    
    eq1 = sp.Eq(y1, x**2)
    eq2 = sp.Eq(y2, x)
    
    solutions = sp.solve((eq1, eq2), (x, y2), dict=True)
    print(solutions)


Method-02

    import sympy as sp
    
    x = sp.symbols('x')
    y1 = x**2
    y2 = x
    
    solutions = sp.solve([y1 - x**2, y2 - x], x)
    print(solutions)


Hope your queries are resolved.

just tidying the code blocks and found Method:-01 fails for me with ValueError: duplicate symbols given!
